# tox unable to find boto3 even though it is installed

Tags: python, boto3, tox

I have a `Python` `tox` project where I run the tox for running the test case and I came across one error a few hours back and am unable to resolve it till now. My module is using boto3 library and is installed using both the commands:

```
pip3 install boto3  

pip install boto3 //for venv environments
```

When I try to install it again it gives me the below stack trace:

```
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.26.34)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.34 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3) (1.29.34)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.34->boto3) (1.26.13)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.34->boto3) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.34->boto3) (1.16.0)
```

But when I run tox it gives me the below error:

```
 File "/Users/tony/IdeaProjects/abc/provisioner/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/api/lambda_handler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

Is there some path issue? I am using `Python 3.8.10`. I tried uninstalling and installing the packages but nothing changed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tox` creates an isolated environment for building and testing. So, when you install a package somewhere, here `boto3` with pip/pip3, maybe system-wide, `tox` ignores that - and that is a good thing, otherwise it would be impossible to have a clean test environment.

You need to provide the necessary dependencies to `tox`.

`tox` automatically installs a package, ie. when there is a `setup.py` or a `pyproject.toml`. You could also provide your dependencies directly via the `deps` configuration key:

```
[testenv]
commands = ...
deps = boto3
```

There is another way. You could "break" the test isolation by using the `tox-current-env` plugin, see https://pypi.org/project/tox-current-env/

**Disclaimer**

I am on of the `tox` maintainers.

Comment: Also, I have added a couple of dependencies in the `setup.py` file. It works fine but it is unable to identify boto3 when added to the `setup.py` file. Why is this so?

Comment: It worked like a charm. You seriously made my day :) I was stuck in this for hours and couldn't find a relevant solution to my problem. Thanks once again. Just help me with my first comment doubt whenever you get a chance :)

Comment: If you still experience issues with a package not being installed, please create a new issue and make sure to post the relevant files, ie `setup.py`. Also consider to try to install the package directly with pip to rule out a toy issue, ie `pip install .`

Comment: I did that. Packages are shown in the `site-packages` however, it wasn't identified by tox. But your trick worked. No other posts mentioned it.